# change color in table for a button

Tags: css

I have a html table

```
    <table class="table table-no-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ip</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ip">
                <button name="nextIpAddress" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Next</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When i hover it  my css look like

```
    .table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th{
        background: #398439 !important;
        color: whitesmoke !important; 
    }

    .btn-link:hover{

    }
```

only in the case of the table, when there is button  i want to display it it's text with white color (same thing if i hover the link)

Solution

.table-hover tbody tr:hover td .btn-link

Comment: @Sudhakar: his HTML doesn't contain a `<tbody>` element, however one will be inserted in the DOM, so the selector should still match; demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9uc8akxL/3/

Comment: The question is very unclear. `when there is button`? Is that an `if() else {}` expression?? If button is there, text is white else not. ..?

Comment: in the html page i can have a button who use btn-link  class and another one in a table like the example i created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to add `<tbody>` elements to your table (see below) or modify your CSS selectors.

```
<table class="table table-no-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="ip">
              <button name="nextIpAddress" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Next</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

or modify the CSS

```
.table-hover tr:hover td, .table-hover tr:hover th{
    background: #398439 !important;
    color: whitesmoke !important; 
}

.btn-link:hover{

}
```

Comment: "*You either need to add `<tbody>` elements to your table...or modify your CSS selectors [to remove the `tbody`]*" - no, if no `<tbody>` is present then one will be inserted automatically in the DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/9uc8akxL/3/

Comment: @DavidThomas I try to not promote shoddy coding practices

Comment: Perhaps, but "*should, for best-practice*" is not the same as "*need to.*"